# rule not substituting target % with prerequisite %

Tags: makefile

The project actually has a ton of different directories where the source files are located so Im simplifying a bit.

SOURCES variable contains:

```
src/main.cpp src/test.cpp
```

the target rule $(BUILD_PATH)%.o expands to:

```
linux_build/test.o
```

so I'm trying to make a rule that takes the target, looks at the "nodir"  part and tries to match it with the corresponding entry from the SOURCES list. It then uses that as it's prerequisite:

```
$(BUILD_PATH)%.o: $(strip $(foreach path, $(SOURCES), $(if $(findstring %.cpp,$(path)), $(path),)))
    $(CL) $(CL_FLAGS) $(INC) $< -o $@
```

the thing that does not seem to work is the % in "%.cpp". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just do `vpath %.cpp $(sort $(dir $(SOURCES)))` and no worries.

Comment: When make parses a makefile it first expands all the targets and prerequisites.  Then later when it wants to try to build  something it will go through the implicit (pattern in this case) rules and expand the stem characters (`%`).  That means that `%.cpp` is treated literally when the prerequisites are expanded and since there's no string `%.cpp` in your `$(SOURCES)` variable, that expands to the empty string.

Comment: @Matt that lead me in the right direction, thanks!